# WordPress integration with GitHub without cmd line access nor local development?

Tags: plugin-development, local-installation, version-control

I've installed WordPress via cPanel and made a small web site. All was done without local development, I just logged into the WordPress using a web browser and did the whole web there.

I don't have command line access in the cPanel, only the File Manager.

I'd like to use my GitHub account to keep the WordPress files, push changes to be able to track them, and also for backup reasons. Is it at all possible to connect cPanel/WordPress with GitHub without command line access and without setting up the local development environment?

Comment: It would depend on your host. Some hosts offer this. You’ll need to speak to them.